# Why does the following Scala code throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: scala

If I instantiate Base2 it runs fine

```
class Base2 {

  class Benchmark {
    def onTrade() {
      println("base onTrade")
    }
  }

  protected val benchmark = new Benchmark
  benchmark.onTrade
}

class Base3 extends Base2 {

  override val benchmark = new Benchmark {
    override def onTrade() {
      println("sub onTrade")
    }
  }
}

// to run
new Base3
```

Exception info:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Base2.<init>(<console>:16)
    at Base3.<init>(<console>:19)
    at .<init>(<console>:10)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:11)
...
```

Comment: Don't override concrete vals. That way lies madness (or, more to the point, non-working software).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base2 is *initialized first* at which time `benchmark.onTrade` is executed, however the member `benchmark` from Base3 (not Base2!) is being used because of the override (`benchmark` in Base2 is actually initialized first, but it doesn't matter because the other `benchmark` is being "bound" to!). I am fairly certain this has to do with the val being *virtual*...

Base3's initialization won't start (or resume?) until after Base2's is finished and thus `Base3.benchmark` is still null at `benchmark.onTrade`.

FWIW, a "lazy val" seems to "fix" the issue.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know scala but could it be something like:

`Base3`'s `benchmark` instance is not constructed until after all the code in `Base2` (`benchmark.onTrade`) has been executed?