# Mystery behavior of val, lazy val and def with an implicit conversion in my scala app

Tags: java, scala, implicit-conversion, playframework-2.1

I have tested three variation of the same code and I got it to work just fine. I want to know why the different behavior.

So I have this working code, which converts a long time stamp to a string of the ECMA date standard format :

```
  lazy val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")

  implicit def dateToECMAFormat(time: Long) = new {
    def asECMADateString: String = {
      dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(time))
    }
  }
```

Other variation that works :

```
  implicit def dateToECMAFormat(time: Long) = new {
    val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")

    def asECMADateString: String = {
      dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(time))
    }
  }
```

But I do not want the SimpleDateFormat to be re instanciated all the time . So I prefere the first one. But now the real mystery :

```
  val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")

  implicit def dateToECMAFormat(time: Long) = new {
    def asECMADateString: String = {
      dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(time))
    }
  }
```

This last piece of code compiles but throws an exception at run-time; I did not manage to get the stack trace from play framework. I just know my controller in play framework 2.1 return with a 500 (Internal Server Error) without any more information (the other controllers work though and the main services are still up).

In each case the call looks like this: `100000L.asECMADateString`

Can someone explain to me the different behaviors and why does the last one does not work? I though I had a good grasp of the difference between val, lazy val and def, but now I feel like I am missing something.

### UPDATE

The code is called in object like this :

```
object MyController extends Controller{

  implicit val myExecutionContext = getMyExecutionContext

  lazy val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.sssZ")

  implicit def dateToECMAFormat(time: Long) = new {
    def asECMADateString: String = {
      dateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(time))
    }
  }

  def myAction = Action {
    Async {
     future {
       blocking{
         //here get some result from a db
         val result = getStuffFromDb
         result.someLong.asECMADateString
       }
     } map { result => Ok(result) } recover { /* return some error code */ }
   }
  }
}
```

It is your basic playframework Async action call.

Comment: Looks very much like you are getting a NPE due to the way (non lazy) vals are initialized. This issue comes up time and time again on SO, see by example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217822/why-does-the-following-scala-code-throw-a-nullpointerexception, or again https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order. But please, give more information (preferably a self contained code snippet reproducing the error) so that we don't have to guess.

Comment: As a side note, `SimpleDateFormat` contains mutable state and is not synchronized, and using it from multiple threads may cause problems. To quote the javadoc, _"Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally."_

Comment: What is the enclosing object/class? Does it mix-in `DelayedInit`?

Comment: The declaration of the lazy val and the implicit def are within an `object` that inherit from `Controller`. The calls to the conversion are with other threads spawned using the `scala.concurrent.future` function. Should I be using DynamicVariable? How should I use it to instantiate as few SimpleDateFormat as necessary?

Comment: There are *no* subclasses of `MyController`?

Comment: No subclasses. It is a very simple service

Answer (score 2):

Since the difference between the 1st and 3rd examples are the `lazy val`, I'd be looking at exactly *where* your call (`100000L.asECMADateString`) is being made.  `lazy val` helps correct some "order of initialization" issues with mix-ins, for example: see [this recent issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16633480) to see if it's similar to yours.

Comment: I believe it is the same issue. But rather than synchronizing I would like to try use `ThreadLocal` as it seems to give the best performance; source: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-best-practices-dateformat-in.html   Any idea on how to do this with scala.util.DynamicVariable?

Comment: I believe to gain any further coherent answers that you need to provide additional information as others have suggested.  For example, it's not clear from your code that there are additional threads involved.  You really need to provide a short (as possible) example that demonstrates your problem, and obtain the exception stack track.

Comment: lazy val works ... it's the simple val outside the def that doesnt.